# Set cognito identity pool providers role resolution via Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cognito, terraform-provider-aws

im trying to deploy cognito for opensearch via terraform. I have a manually built cognito working and ow trying to port it to terraform.

does anyone know how to set the below part?:

- Choose role from token
- role resolution 'DENY'

[image: cognito auth role selection]

Terraform for the identity pool:

```
resource "aws_cognito_identity_pool" "cognito-identity-pool" {
  identity_pool_name               = "opensearch-${var.domain_name}-identity-pool"
  allow_unauthenticated_identities = false

  cognito_identity_providers {
    client_id               = aws_cognito_user_pool_client.cognito-user-pool-client.id
    provider_name           = aws_cognito_user_pool.cognito-user-pool.endpoint
  }
}
```

ive tried adding `server_side_token_check = false` but no joy..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a different resource, namely `aws_cognito_identity_pool_roles_attachment` [1]. In order to achieve the same thing you see in the AWS console, you need to add the following block:

```
resource "aws_cognito_identity_pool_roles_attachment" "name" {
  identity_pool_id = aws_cognito_identity_pool.cognito-identity-pool.id
  roles = {
    "authenticated" = <your-role-arn>
  }
  role_mapping {
    ambiguous_role_resolution = "Deny"
    type                      = "Token"
    identity_provider         = "${aws_cognito_user_pool.cognito-user-pool.endpoint}:${aws_cognito_user_pool_client.cognito-user-pool-client.id}"
  }
}
```

Note that the `roles` block is required and the key can be `authenticated` or `unathenticated`. Additionally, you will probably have to figure out what kind of permissions the role will need and create it. The example in the documentation can be used as a blueprint. There are also other settings like `mapping_rule` block which might be of use to you, but since the details are lacking I omitted it from the answer.

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cognito_identity_pool_roles_attachment